# How can I align 3 UIButtons to the center of an UITableCellView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, autolayout

How can I align 3 `UIButton`s to the center of an `UITableCellView`?

For example say I have 3 `UIButton`s with titles:

1. Email
2. Phone
3. Skype

It is possible for one or more of the `UIButton`s to be hidden. For example, if the Phone `UIButton` is hidden then only Email and Skype should be aligned in the center. If Phone and Skype is hidden then only Email should be aligned in the center.

When any of the `UIButton`s are hidden, the visible ones should be aligned in the center.

I want to center them both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: you want to align them vertically and horizontally both, or just vertically and place them side wise?

Comment: I would subclass the cell and set the frames of the buttons in layoutSubviews:

Comment: iOS 9 introduced the [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) that is designed for this kind of situation.

Comment: @deanware: that's exactly what this is made for, +1

Comment: Also, [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views) can help

Comment: @Mr.T : No, i am not using xib but creating scenes with storyboard. I have UITableView.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Tested for xcode 7:**

i suppose your are looking for something like that

[image]

**Solution:**

[image]

**Steps:**
**1)** what is needed is an encapsulating view which holds all three buttons (skype, phone, email) into center irrespective of whether there is one button, two or three inside it. For that a holder view is created which is shown with green background in below snapshot.[image]

constraints for that holder view are

[image]

it is just to hold all the subviews, it will get its size from its content so no need to give it height/width constraints.

**2)** now constraints for the button in the center will be

[image]

**3)** constraints for buttons on either side will be

[image]

*If you need to hide any button just make its width constraint constant to 0 and all the other buttons will be rearranged accordingly*

**For TableView Cell:**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var emailButtonWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneButtonWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet weak var skypeButtonWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?

    func showButtons(showSkype showSkype : Bool, showEmail : Bool, showPhone : Bool ){
        emailButtonWidthConstraint?.constant = showEmail ? 54.0 : 0.0
        phoneButtonWidthConstraint?.constant = showPhone ? 54.0 : 0.0
        skypeButtonWidthConstraint?.constant = showSkype ? 54.0 : 0.0

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

**Use:**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: true, showEmail: true, showPhone: true)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: false, showEmail: true, showPhone: true)
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: true, showEmail: false, showPhone: true)
        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: true, showEmail: true, showPhone: false)
        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: false, showEmail: false, showPhone: true)
        } else if indexPath.row == 5 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: false, showEmail: true, showPhone: false)
        } else if indexPath.row == 6 {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: true, showEmail: false, showPhone: false)
        } else {
            cell?.showButtons(showSkype: true, showEmail: true, showPhone: true)
        }

        return cell!
    }
```

Same can be achieved with UIStackView (without all this headache obviously) but that won't run on iOS prior to 9.0

**Updated (26th Oct 2015) :**

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/usamaiqbal83/AutolayoutButtonAllign) for test project

Comment: can you post the objective-c version of the same ?

Comment: Implementation for objective-c would be exactly same (you just need to change the syntax)

Comment: I am having trouble implementing constraints. I'm new to auto-layout. Also I need some padding between each button. Can you guide in right approach ?

Comment: @Usama Is this possible without tableview? I would like 7 buttons center aligned. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into UIStackView (however, it's for iOS 9 an up).

I believe there is a method for UIStackViews in which embedded UIViews "disappear", and it'll re-align the other UIViews that are embedded in the same UIStackView.

Comment: Thanks but i am using ios less than ios9 so i can't use UIStackView is there any other option to do that?

Comment: I can't think of any ways to do it via storyboards. I suggest learning how to edit layouts via code.